# Use saved credit card information for authorize.net

Tags: payment-methods, authorize.net

In magento when we place order by using payment method authorize.net. The credit card information entered saved into the database. Next time when same customer wants place order then saved credit cards should show on checkout payment page.  customer should use it so that no need to retype again. Customer should manage this credit card information from my account section. Any idea how can do this? Any extension available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Authorize.Net service for storing credit cards is Customer Information Manager (CIM).  There are several extensions that should meet your needs if you start with this search: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=authorize.net+cim&pl=0

Comment: Have you had experience with any oft these?